# jQuery draggable background image change on mouse shake

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, animated-gif

I've been playing with jQuery-UI Draggable https://www.jcmatheson.com/page/blog.html and was wondering if there was a way of changing the gif to a different background image if you drag and shook it hard enough with the mouse? Basically, you drag the sleeping head around and if shook, changes to a waking expression jpg.

Sorry if this is quite vague, I'm very new to jQuery and this is my first question on SO.

Thanks!

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
```

```css
#draggable { width: 256px; height: 256px; padding: 0.5em; }

.ui-widget-content {
    border: none;
    background: #ffffff url(https://piskel-imgstore-b.appspot.com/img/5505e3cf-b2a5-11e7-a7d6-77854951e175.gif) 50% 50% repeat-x!important;
    color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It helps if you produce come code, preferably in the plunker of FiddleJs or similar so people can jump in and help.  I am gonna help you get started you wanna use  mousedrag events coupled with some calculations and timer in order to define a "shook".

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of mousedrag events. Will probably give that a go if I can't find a solution for this.

Comment: You could use a `setInterval()` function and mesure the amount of pixels moved in that time. If moved more than 100px 3 times in a row, that could mean it's been shaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a setInterval() function and mesure the amount of pixels moved in that time. If moved more than 25px 3 times in a row, that could mean it's been shaken

```js
$(".shakeMe").draggable({
   
});

var lastLeft;
var shakeCount = 0;
var lastShake = 'right';
setInterval(function(){
   left = $(".shakeMe").offset().left;
   // var dist = Math.abs(lastLeft - left);
   var dist = lastLeft - left;
   if(dist > 25 && lastShake == 'right') {
      shakeCount++;
      lastShake == 'right';
      if(shakeCount >= 3) {
          $(".shakeMe").css("background", "red");
      }
   } else {
      if(dist < -25 && lastShake == 'left') {
         shakeCount++;
         lastShake == 'left';
      if(shakeCount >= 3) {
          $(".shakeMe").css("background", "red");
      }
      }
      shakeCount = 0;
   }
   console.info(shakeCount);
   lastLeft = left;
   
}, 200);
```

This is running every 200ms (one fifth of a second) but this could be reduced.

Also, you have to move it 25px 3 times in a row, so it depends what you what a "shake" to actually be

https://codepen.io/OliWebBoss/pen/mBQNxJ